# Tabbed Activity template in Android Studio not working on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 1.1.0.

I created a new project using the Android Studio Wizard and selected MinimumSDK: API 15, and Tabbed Activity.

The target SDK is automatically set to API 21.

When I run this project (with no modifications) on a Genymotion Nexus 5, API19 (4.4.4) emulator everything looks as expected.

When I run this project (with no modifications) on a Genymotion Nexus 6, API21 (5.0.0) emulator, I only get a blank white screen.

This is the generated onCreate in MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

Android Studio tells me that

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
```

are deprecated, which may explain why they don't work in my API21 device.

How do I change these deprecated methods to work on API21 and still work in

I'm frustrated that Android Studio's templates don't work for the latest API.

Comment: Since action bar tabs were deprecated in API Level 21, use some other tab implementation. Particularly if you want a `ViewPager`, there is `PagerTabStrip` in the Android Support package and a bunch of open source ones (e.g., `PagerSlidingTabStrip`). The pages being empty is due to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87742).

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr This behavior persisted over multiple runs but works now after deleting and recreating the emulator

I implemented the code that CommonsWare referenced in [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87742) and still saw a blank screen.

I placed a breakpoint in my code and the Genymotion Lollipop Emulator locked up. I was unable to restart it successfully.

I deleted the emulator and reinstalled and now the modified code is working.

Just to verify, I created a new project as before and it works in the newly created Lollipop Emulator too.

Much to my frustration, I am unable to replicate the original bug I saw.